# With `ansible-config list`, what means yaml?

Tags: ansible

When I launch a command `ansible-config list`, some configuration entries had a `yaml` field, for example :

```
DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE:
  default: null
  description: The vault password file to use. Equivalent to --vault-password-file or --vault-id
  env:
  - {name: ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE}
  ini:
  - {key: vault_password_file, section: defaults}
  name: Vault password file
  type: path
  yaml: {key: defaults.vault_password_file}
```

I know how to use field `env: {name: ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE}` and field `ini: {key: vault_password_file, section: defaults}`.

How can I use `yaml: {key: defaults.vault_password_file}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's evidently designed to make people ask questions after carefully reading the output from `ansible-config` :-D

But, seriously, it is apparently part of an aspirational world in which [config/manager.py reads YAML](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/27448) but in practice it is just one fat [FIXME](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.0/lib/ansible/config/manager.py#L285)

Reasonable people can certainly differ about whether that stuff should be removed until it works for real, if for no other reason than this question right here. Feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) if you think it would be ideally removed.